# Startup BIOS messages go to my TV, not to my LCD display

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

MB: Asus P7H55

VC: NVIDIA GTX 260

(**NOTE:** I had same problem when VC was GT 240 and the MB was Asus P5B, too).

In short: every time I restart/turn-on my computer, the BIOS startup messages and the boot loader (I dual-boot XP/Debian) goes to my TV, not to my LCD. **NOTE:** We are talking about two psyshical screens; my VC has 1 DVI and 1 RGB slot -- TV is on the RGB, the LCD is on the DVI.

What did I try:

1. Swapped the places on the videocard where the TV and the LCD are plugged in. No effect whatsoever. It's like the VC prefers the TV at startup time.
2. Looked the NVIDIA control panel and the Windows' display settings. At both places, my LCD is set as primary. Of course, it does become primary, once the NVIDIA driver gets loaded during the Windows startup (my problem is related only to startup, not after the OS loads).
3. Looked for options in the BIOS, couldn't find any. I remember my old MB (Asus P5B) had an option of something like "Video controller preference" (or priority, or something close), which had the options "PEG/PCI" and "PCI/PEG". I also remember changing them around didn't help at all. However, my current MB (Asus P7H55) doesn't even have that. Couldn't find anything related to this.
4. Googled tirelessly for days. Found 2-3 similar complaint threads, all of which suggested exactly the things I already tried.

I will appreciate any resonable suggestion and will try it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have thought that switching which port they are plugged into would switch it. It's definitely not a nVidia driver problem because the BIOS happens before the HDD is accessed.

It might end up being a preference of VGA first, DVI second. There may not be a way to change that.

Comment: Thought about that and I am horrified by the prospect. :(  Thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: It's almost CERTAINLY a preference of VGA first, DVI second.  Pretty much every video card anywhere ever that doesn't output on all outputs will always default to a specific one.  There isn't squat you can do about this unless you can physically alter the cabling.  I am fairly surprised that card doesn't output on all, though.

Comment: I would be satisfied if anyone can provide a link with such an official claim...

Comment: Curiously enough, after me ripping the computer apart (added RAM, removed the CPU fan to clean it, etc.), then I figured "what the hell, let's try it", I did dwap the slots of the monitor and the TV, and THIS time it worked! Oh dear. Didn't work 3 months ago. Marking this as the answer.